# Reloading a custom VF page in Lightning mode loads first page which has been navigated using sforce.one

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-ready, visualforce-in-lightning

We are using sforce.one js object for navigating custom VF page in Lightning mode. We have added custom VF page on record page from where navigation takes place to different custom VF pages using sforce.one. The navigation works seamlessly. But on nth level page (n > 1) if we click browser's reload button it loads the first page which has been navigated using sforce.one.

For e.g. From record page first we navigate to 'P1' page using sforce.one. Then from 'P1' page we navigate to 'P2' page using sforce.one. Then on 'P2', If we reload the page then it loads 'P1'.

I have checked in chrome (V-56.0.2924.87), Firefox (V-52.0.2).

Any help will be appreciated.